# Limit number of textarea characters per line in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my text area, I should be able to enter only 13 characters per line in multiline textarea. In each line i need to check whether the value the user entered is 13 characters If suppose the user has entered less than 13 i need to show the alert message...How can i do that?? In the below code i have restricted space,dot etc from the input..

```js
$('#splitLines').keypress(function(e) {
  if (!((e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) ||
      (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) ||
      (e.which >= 96 && e.which <= 105) ||
      (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) ||
      e.which == 13)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="11" cols="60" name="txtarea[]" id="splitLines" value=""></textarea>
```

Comment: At what point yout to show the alert? Any button click?

Comment: @zam Abdul Vahid yes on submit button click

Comment: @Zam Abdul Vahid okay i m working on it

Comment: updated the code to restrict 13 characters per line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing:

```
$('#btn').on("click", function(e) {
  let num = $("#splitLines").val().split('\n')
  //get value and split it into new lines
  console.clear()
  console.log(num)
  num.forEach(e => {
  // for each new line
    let n = e.split("")
    //get number of chars
    console.log(n.length)
    if (n.length !== 13) {
    // if some line dos not have 13:
      alert("Each line needs 13 char")
    } else {
    // all good
      console.log(true)
    }
  })
});
```

Simplified solution:

```js
$('#btn').on("click", function(e) {
  $("#splitLines").val().split('\n').forEach(e => {
    e.split("").length !== 13 ? alert("Each line needs 13 char") : console.log(true)
  })
});
```

```css
1234567890123
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="11" cols="60" name="txtarea[]" id="splitLines" value=""></textarea>
<button type="button" id="btn">test</button>
```

And if you want to alert the line number of errors:

```js
$('#btn').on("click", function(e) {
  $("#splitLines").val().split('\n').forEach(function callback(e, index) {
    e.split("").length !== 13 ? alert(`Each line needs 13 char, error on line ${index+1}`) : console.log(true)
  })
});
```

```css
1234567890123
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="11" cols="60" name="txtarea[]" id="splitLines" value=""></textarea>
<button type="button" id="btn">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use .split("\n") to get the number of lines & then check its length to get the count.

```js
$('#splitLines').keypress(function(e) {
  if (!((e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) ||
      (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) ||
      (e.which >= 96 && e.which <= 105) ||
      (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) ||
      e.which == 13)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});

// Restrict to 13 characters
$("#splitLines").keyup(function (event) {
    var maxlength = 13;

    var text = $(this).val();
    var lines = text.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm); 
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].length > maxlength) {
            lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, maxlength);
        }
    }
    $(this).val(lines.join(''));
});

//Show alert based on line length
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
  var text = $('#splitLines').val();
  
  lineCount = 0;
  flag = false;
  if (text) {
    var lines = text.split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      console.log('each line length', lines[i].length);
       
      if (lines[i].length < 13) flag = true;
      if (lines[i].length > 0) lineCount++;
    }
    console.log('total lines with text', lineCount);
    if (flag === true) alert('Less than 13 in a line');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea rows="11" cols="60" name="txtarea[]" id="splitLines" value=""></textarea>
<button id="btnSubmit">Get Line Counts</button>
```

Comment: This would be the better approach....tqsm

Comment: Glad i could help. Appreciate if you could mark the answer as accepted as it would help other community members who are looking for similar solutions.

Comment: "ReferenceError: flag is not defined", if all is good

Comment: flat = false; there is a spelling mistake "flat" change it to flag